# Displaying sqlite query (via php) in browser

Tags: php, sqlite

Hi there i am struggling to code a table that will display the query that i have written into the browser. I have tried multiple times but have failed. Can someone help me format a view for the following query ?

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:daypilot.sqlite'); 
$start = '2018-02-20'; 
$end = '2018-02-25'; 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE end > ? AND start < ?'; 
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); $stmt->execute([$start, $end]); 
$events = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

foreach ($events as $event) { 
    var_dump($event); // output with your desired formatting here 
}
```

Comment: <?php
$db = new PDO('sqlite:daypilot.sqlite');

$start = '2018-02-20';
$end = '2018-02-25';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE `end` > ? AND `start` < ?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$start, $end]);
$events = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($events as $event) {
    var_dump($event);  // output with your desired formatting here
}
?>

Comment: thats the code (forgot to include in post)

Comment: You should edit your actual post and paste the code in there instead. Additionally, you should be sure to format it so that it's readable.

Comment: Im trying to post the code in the edit option but it keeps saying to format it correctly which i am doing...

Comment: Got it !! Any help with this is appreciated as its the last element to my system

Comment: @Ryan you should highlight the code and then click on '{}' for it to be formatted.

Comment: Can you try to change your code to `$start = '2018-02-20  00:00:00'; 
$end = '2018-02-25  00:00:00'; 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE Datetime(end) > ? AND Datetime(start) < ?';` and see if it helps

Comment: the query executes with the code i use. I just need a table or some sort of view to help me display the result